# How to access keycloak on subpath with nginx ingress?

Tags: keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, keycloak-services

I have nginx ingress controller in my EKS cluster along with keycloak i tried to expose it on a subpath (myhost.com/keycloak) but it doesn't work so after few researchs i found that i should add this env variable to keycloak deployment : **PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true** and now i can only access it through myhost.com/auth. So is there any way to customize that path
to something like myhost.com/keycloak

Here is my Ingress resource :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "keycloak-ingress"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    app: keycloak-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myhost.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /auth
            backend:
              serviceName: keycloak
              servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Manage-subsystem](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_installation/#manage-subsystem-configuration) configuration documentations says:

> Low-level configuration of Keycloak is done by editing the standalone.xml, standalone-ha.xml, or domain.xml file in your distribution. The location of this file depends on your operating mode.
>
> While there are endless settings you can configure here, this section will focus on configuration of the keycloak-server subsystem. No matter which configuration file you are using, configuration of the keycloak-server subsystem is the same.
>
> The keycloak-server subsystem is typically declared toward the end of the file like this:
>
> ```
> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
>    <web-context>auth</web-context>
>    ...
> </subsystem>
> ```
>
> > Note that anything changed in this subsystem will not take effect until the server is rebooted.

That results in a fact that the default entrypoint is: http://localhost:8080/auth .

> and now i can only access it through myhost.com/auth

You can adjust your configuration in `standalone.xml`and substitute `auth` with `keycloak` . Additionally it'll be needed to adjust `path` in the ingress.yaml .

Hope that helps.

Comment: is it possible to change that via env variable or the jboss cli somehow?